# Convert ASP.NET Dict to javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui

I am building a Jquery UI autocomplete list and the input needs to be in the following format:

```
var data = [
        { value: "AL", label: "Alabama" },
        { value: "AK", label: "Alaska" },
        { value: "AZ", label: "Arizona" },
        { value: "AR", label: "Arkansas" },
        { value: "CA", label: "California" },];
```

Now I retrieve the data from the ASP.Net I got a key value pairs list look like (in VB.NET)

```
List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
```

Now how can I convert the ASP.NET list to the EXACT format as value, label pair format to feed the autocomplete?

Comment: `List<Dictionary<string, string>> data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript value is an array of objects, with "value" and "label" properties, which is pretty close to your `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))`, except that the property names do not match.  So, all you should need to do is convert each `KeyValuePair` into an object with the correct property names, and then serialize the result to JSON (replace `values` with your actual list).

```vb
Dim values = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))()
values.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(1, "A"))
values.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(2, "B"))
values.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(3, "C"))
values.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(4, "D"))

Dim json = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
    values.Select(Function(x) New With { .value = x.Key, .label = x.Value })
)
```

`json` will be:

```
[{"value":1,"label":"A"},{"value":2,"label":"B"},{"value":3,"label":"C"},{"value":4,"label":"D"}]
```

I don't know how you are getting this into your JavaScript, but maybe something like:

```
var data = JSON.parse('<%= json %>');
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks a lot. unfortunately I don't have enough  reputation to rate you. 
To get it into javascript I used 
                var jsonObj =  <%= jsonLIST%>;
Thank you!

Comment: @RaySun You should be able to accept the answer (check mark next to the answer), which will also add to your reputation a little.